# Fetch Auth. Provider Callback URL in Flows

Tags: url, screen-flow, auth-provider, callback, flowscreen

I have successfully created Auth. Provider from my ScreenFlow.

I want to display the callback URL in the same flow.

Can someone please tell me whether there is any way to fetch the Callback URL of a specific Auth. provider in the flow?

I appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Create an Apex class that does this, then call it via invocable action. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/74094/query-client-configuration-from-auth-provider-e-g-sso-initialization-url

Comment: Thank you so much @identigral, though this will return the SSO URL, it can be modified and the problem will be resolved. Thanks once again

Comment: Please add this as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the guideline by @identigral I have managed to obtain the callback URL by using the following approach - here Sample_Auth is the developer name for the Auth Provider

*String ssoUrl = Auth.AuthConfiguration.getAuthProviderSsoUrl(null,null,'Sample_Auth');*

*String callbackUrl = ssoUrl.substringBefore('/auth');*

*callbackUrl += '/authcallback/Sample_Auth';*

I found this can also be achieved with help of the URL class, which is much easier to work with.

*String baseUrl = URL.getOrgDomainUrl().toExternalForm();*

*String callbackUrl = baseUrl+'/services/authcallback/Sample_Auth';*